# Execute an EC2 command via the browser (Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-sheets

I need to execute a command on AWS EC2 on demand, rather than a scheduled cron. How can I trigger a script on the command line on my EC2 by just using the web browser?

I have made an attempt via a webhook via Zapier but struggling to link this into the EC2 CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Systems Manager Run Command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) or [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) over SSH (example [here](https://abhishek-tiwari.com/post/interacting-with-tagged-ec2-instances-using-fabric), though it won't work from within a browser).

[image]